# How to transfer Object c to Swift aout collectionVIewLayout

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I have took below website as reference, and tried to convert this to Swift code. Refer to “collectioViewLayout” part, I have difficulties to make things in order.

Appreciated that.[UICollectionVIew circlesLayout](https://github.com/jelenakrmar/circlesLayout)

> The original code is as below:-

```
- (CGSize)sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([[self.collectionView.delegate class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout)]) {
    return [(id)self.collectionView.delegate collectionView:self.collectionView layout:self sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
return CGSizeMake(0, 0);}
```

> My revised swift code as follows:-

```
func sizeForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize {
    if type(of: collectionView.delegate) is UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            return collectionView!.delegate?.collectionView!(collectionView!, layout: self, sizeForItemAt: indexPath) ?? CGSize.zero
        }
        return CGSize.zero
    }
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

However, some errors appeared. (see below)

> Part 1) Cast from 'UICollectionViewDelegate?.Type' to unrelated type 'UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout' always fails

> Part 2) Incorrect argument labels in call (have '*:layout:sizeForItemAt:', expected'*:targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt:toProposedIndexPath:')

Is there anyone who can guide me how to fix those problem into correct swift code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C code checks the type of `collectionView.delegate`, but in Swift you have to do a cast to tell the compiler that you are sure that it is indeed of type `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`{

```
func sizeForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath?) -> CGSize {
    // "as?" does the cast, evaluating the expression to nil if it fails.
    if let delegate = collectionView!.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
        // you can combine these two checks into one if statement. Just separate them with ","
        let indexPath = indexPath {
        return delegate.collectionView?(collectionView, layout: self, sizeForItemAt: indexPath) ?? .zero
    }
    return .zero
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help :) 
To be specific, I was trying to transfer Object C to Swift for CirclesLayout.m

However, I have applied what you have suggested and there is no further warning from compliers. 
BUT! There is no result on collectionView. 

Any chance you are willing to render assistance on my code please? 
If okay, I will pass you for your advice. 

Thanks a lot!